# Is different media query breakpoints from different browsers (Android) what one should expect in general?

Tags: android, css, cross-browser, media, device-width

I tested media query, using six different browsers in a Huawei Ascend Y330/Android 4.2 and got three different device-width results reported by mqtest.io.

For each browser, I then tested the actual breakpoints on my own html-page with css like:
`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px)` -- and by altering the pixel-value until formating-change showed up. Device-width in all six cases agree with what was reported by mqtest.io for the device.

Obviously, the problem is one can't control the design because the browser inconsistency. Is this a »local» problem or is it a general problem when using `@media`?

**Results according to mqtest.io and the web page test**

> Dolphin and Android default browser
>  device-width: 480px
>   device-height: 800px
>
> Opera and Google Chrome
>  device-width: 320px
>  device-height:
>   534px
>
> Firefox and Firefox Beta
>  device-width: 320px
>  device-height:
>   533px
>
> Screen: 480x800
>  Pixel ratio: 1.5 (as reported by mqtest.io for all
>   six browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Does the following piece of code fix the issue?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that code in the test page but it doesn't help. Also, I ran a few more tests and it becomes obvious that device-width simply is unpredictable. Thanks for you answer.